# Authentication Middleware application for routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, redux

This is a general question. I have web application with typical Sign up , Log In.I am using MERN stack. I have a middleware auth.js, that validates the existing user, when logged in, using the login route page.

My question  is, is this validation enough, for user to access other routes in the web application. For example, i have routes where user need to post  comments and get data from the database.

SO

1. Wouldnt my first login in route, protects subsequent routes?
2. Or,Do I need to have the auth middleware used in all those routes?
3. Are there any standards or set rules to implement auth middelware to certain type of routes
4. How much it would affect the performance/speed of web application, if auth middleware is applied to every route.

Please bear with me as i am new in programming. I appreciate more pertinent details for this question, so that I can learn

thanks
sal

Comment: You will have to authenticate user before accessing any route which should be authorised.

Comment: Thanks Sacchi. Thats what i did, In the Login In route, do i need to use this it for other routes as well?

Comment: If it’s a parent route of all the routes then you don’t need other route to handle auth, but in case you have separate routes then you might have to keep auth middleware for every route

Comment: so for instance '/login' is the parent route(where i have auth middleware), if i have another route' /login/user/' then login is parent of user,,,,,, but if i have a separate route'/user' or '/user/id', then i need to keep auth middleware here as well, since the parent 'login' is not here. is this correct?